# xyz with pitch yaw and roll --> xy

Tags: math, 3d, operation

i want to calculate the 2d coordinates on the screen (xy positions) of a point using its xyz coordinates and the camera's pitch, yaw and roll. how do i do this? i have searched it up on google, but every time i always get shown something different than what i want, like "how to find pitch yaw and roll from xyz" or it uses data other than my xyz coordinates and pitch yaw and roll of the camera. i just want an operation using on the camera xyz, the point xyz and the camera pitch yaw and roll.

i tried using rotation matrices, but it only showed "θ" (theta) instead of pitch yaw and roll like i expected, and i barely understand rotation matrices anyways...

big thank you to anyone helping me with this.

Comment: You say "roll, pitch, yaw", but no one know how to use them correctly.
Also, correspondence between "camera" and "screen" is unknown.
At least, defining concrete formula must be done by yourself.
Starting with none of or only one of "roll,pitch,yaw" will be recommended.